# Creating a Ruby hash with key:value lines

Tags: ruby, parsing, hashtable

Here's another "what's the most elegant way to do X in Ruby" type of questions.  Consider the response from a webservice with key:value pairs on each line of the return body, along the lines of

```
key1:val1
key2:val2
key3:val3
```

I want to create a Ruby hash with this data, `{"key1" => "val1", ...}`.  Algorithmically I can git 'er done with

```
hash = {}
body.lines.each do |line|
  key, val = line.split(':')
  hash[key] = val
end
```

but I'm guessing there's a one-liner or two-liner that is even more elegant.

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

```
lines = [
  'key1:val1',
  'key2:val2',
  'key3:val3'
]

hash = Hash[lines.map {|it| it.split(':', 2)}]
```

**Explanation**

[`Hash[object]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) creates a new hash from the object. Where the object is one of:

- List of elements
- List of pairs
- Object that can be converted to hash

Comment: That works like a charm, what is the explanation of the Hash[] syntax?  I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: `it` is not a specially meaningful name, why not simply `line`? note also that `split(':', 2)` would allow colons in the value.

Comment: Can't tell where I acquired this habit. Probably from groovy. For me it stands for just it :) or for iterator.

Comment: So i gathered, but in the Ruby world the concept `iterator` just does not exist :-) just a detail, in my experience giving meaningful names to variables helps a lot.

Comment: @tokland I agree with you that proper naming is vital for maintainable code. I just think that variables with one line scope can have shorter names without hurting readability.

Comment: We're bike shedding here, but I would agree with using `line` instead of `it`

Answer (score 1):

if you have pairs of objects, than `Hash[]` is your friend:

```
Hash[lines.map {|key_val| key_val.split(":")}]
=> {"key1"=>"val1", "key2"=>"val2", "key3"=>"val3"}
```

damn, too slow...

Answer (score 0):

There are caret returns in the post, so real topic solution is

```
hash = Hash[lines.split(/\s/).map {|line| line.split(':', 2)}]
```